# Sending variable inside curl with '' shielding

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I can execute api-call using terraform, but not bash.

This terraform code works:

```
curl -X POST https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/some-organization/${var.repository_name}/envvar \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'Circle-Token: ${data.aws_ssm_parameter.ct[0].value}' \
 -d '{"name":"AWS_ACCOUNT_ID_${upper(var.environment)}","value":"${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"}'
```

This is my bash code that doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
repo=$2
lower_env=$3
env=$(echo "$lower_env" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
token="1234567890"

......
NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId')"
......

  curl -X POST https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/some-organization/$repo/envvar \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H 'Circle-Token:${token}' \
      -d '{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_${env}","value":"\'$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID'\"}'
```

As I understand, main problem happens with passing variable token inside curl, I tried shielding - ' '\ - but no luck.

```
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -H 'Circle-Token: \'$token'\' \
      -d '{"name":"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_${upper(\'$env'\}","value":"\'$NEW_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'\"}'
```

I tried to echo curl itself from bash, it looks correct:

```
curl -X POST https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/some-ogranization/repo-from-token/envvar -H 'Circle-Token: 1234567890'
```

**The working code, the solution:**

```
  curl -X POST "https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/some-organization/$repo/envvar" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Circle-Token: $token" \
      -d "{\"name\":\"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_${env}\",\"value\":\"$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID\"}"
```

Comment: `set -u` is your friend, as is `set -x` to turn on tracing in Bash.  And shellcheck is another friend - get your sysadmin to install it, or submit your code to the online service that can run it for you.

Comment: If you want `$env` to be expanded, you don't want it in single-quotes (as on your last line).

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you very much, totally forgot about this commands! They helped a lot in troubleshooting what is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the syntax for passing the `Circle-Token` header,you used `${data.aws_ssm_parameter.ct[0].value}` to interpolate the value of the `Circle-Token` header, and you used single quotes (`'`) around the `Circle-Token` header value, which prevents variable interpolation,so just use double quotes (`"`) !

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
repo=$2
lower_env=$3
env=${lower_env^^}
token="1234567890"

......

NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$(aws iam list-access-keys --user-name $user | jq -r '.AccessKeyMetadata[].AccessKeyId')"

......

curl -X POST "https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/some-organization/$repo/envvar" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Circle-Token: $token" \
    -d "{\"name\":\"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_${env}\",\"value\":\"$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID\"}"
```

If you like, you could reduce the escaping in the `-d` argument by only exposing the variables to the shell for interpretation rather than the whole argument string either by concatenation:

```
curl ...
    -d '{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_'"${env}"'","value":"'"$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID"'"}'
```

or calling `printf`:

```
curl ...
    -d "$(printf '{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_%s","value":"%s"}' "$PWD" "$HOME")"
```

or by populating a variable to be used as that argument:

```
data='{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_'"${env}"'","value":"'"$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID"'"}'
```

or:

```
printf -v data '{"name":"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_%s","value":"%s"}' "$env" "$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
```

followed by:

```
curl ...
    -d "$data"
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved it with "".
So code looks like this:

  curl -X POST "https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/org/$repo/envvar" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Circle-Token: $token" \
      -d "{\"name\":\"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_${env}\",\"value\":\"$NEW_ACCESS_KEY_ID\"}"